# How to add an object from text input into an array in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const data = {
  0: {
    isEditing:false,
    text: 'Chloe',
  },
  1: {
   isEditing:false,
    text: 'Jasper',
  },
  2: {
    isEditing:false,
    text: 'Pepper',
  }};
```

I want to create an add method for this but I have no clue how to insert the item at the next index. I can't change the structure of array because I need to use the sortable-list library for drag and drop.

Here's my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: "",
      db: []
    };
    this.textChange = this.textChange.bind(this);
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
  }

  textChange = value => {
    const inputValue = value;
    this.setState(() => ({
      inputValue
    }));
  };
  addTask = () => {
    if (!this.state.inputValue) {
      return;
    }
    //this.state.db.push({
     // isEditing:false,
    //  text: this.state.inputValue
   // });

    data.index = {
          isEditing:false,
          text: this.state.inputValue     
    }

    index++;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      data:this.state.data,
      inputValue: ""
    });
    // rowsState - array: {text, isEditing}
  };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find the answer.

```
addTask = () => {
    if (!this.state.inputValue) {
      return;
    }

    let newData = {};

    let l = Object.keys(this.state.data).length;
    console.log("l=", l);
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      let el = this.state.data[i]; // i + ""
      newData[i] = el;
    }

    newData[l] = { text: this.state.inputValue, isEditing: false };

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      data: newData,
      inputValue: ""
    });
  };
```